# Whose corpse is hanging in the courtyard in S02E09?

Tags: game-of-thrones, plot-explanation

In GOT/S2 Ep 9: *Blackwater*, just before the battle for King's Landing, there is one burnt corpse hanging in the background, on the brick wall up high. This is *not* to be confused with the 2 orphan boys hanging back in Winterfell, that Theon killed and burned in his deception of killing Bran Stark and his little brother. This is one lone ( & longer) corpse and it is just outside the courtyard where Bronn is singing the Lannister song with the girly on his knee.

Just wondering who it is meant to be and the significance of that person. I am presuming it does otherwise why bother to have it there at all and in such a significance first frames of that scene?

Answer (score 2):

I've just watched it back a couple of times, and not being able to remember anything of significance from the book. I think it's just placing emphasis on the meaning of The Rains of Castemere. That all who cross the Lannisters, become corpses adorning their walls!

Comment: In the books there was some reference to an anti-Lannister pro-Baratheon conspiracy, where the leaders were caught and then use as the first round of ammunition for the city's defensive catapults. It could be a nod to that, or executing traitors/deserters more generally.

Answer (score 1):

> This is not to be confused with the 2 orphan boys hanging back in Winterfell, that Theon killed and burned in his deception of killing Bran Stark and his little brother.

Those weren’t orphans, they were the children of the farmer whom they also killed and burned their farm.

> In GOT/S2 Ep 9: Blackwater, just before the battle for King's Landing, there is one burnt corpse hanging in the background, on the brick wall up high. This is one lone ( & long) corpse and it is just outside the courtyard where Bronn is singing the Lannister song with the girly on his knee.
>
> Just wondering who it is meant to be and the significance of that person.

The shot in question was an following-shot which followed a couple of random soldiers into the tavern.

> I am presuming it does otherwise why bother to have it there at all and in such a significance first frames of that scene?

Actually, it isn’t significant, it is just an establishing shot leading into the scene with Bronn. The charred body was set-dressing to set the tone, and to show the callous attitude that they have for life, where that they can kill people and leave their corpses lying (or hanging) around without a thought, then go on to sing and drink.

This sort of thing is common on this show where bodies are shown strewn around all over the place.

Comment: The burnt boys at Winterfell ARE orphans.The farmers grown up sons are away fighting for Robb Stark.This was crucial to Theon Greyjoy to pass the dead orphans off as the Stark boys to gain respect from his fellow Ironborn.

Answer (score 0):

It is a straw dummy. In said scene where Bronn and rest of Lannisters are singing before the Battle of Blackwater, there is also a straw man (much smaller)in a noose on the wall when the Hound and accomplice make their entrance to the scene. As for significance, who knows?